# What do I do after "From Within"?

Tags: fallout-4

I beat the quest prior to this where you attack Fort Strong, but the game won't load the next quest.

I'm thinking this has to do with the Insitute - do I have to complete the main story line to continue the Brotherhood of Steel faction story line?

Comment: Have you checked the wiki yet? Here's a link to the [Brotherhood of Steel quests](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_quests#Brotherhood_of_Steel).

Answer (score 2):

Speak to Proctor Ingram at Boston Airport to start the Liberty Reprimed mission or continue with the quests inside the Institute for Father.